# Why do I get this strange error in installing git in ubuntu 20

Tags: git

I am new in Git philosophy and I want to install it on my ubuntu 20 laptop. Following the guide at the url https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git, when I give the command

```
make all doc info
```

I obtain the error

```
SUBDIR git-gui
    SUBDIR gitk-git
    SUBDIR templates
make -C Documentation all
make[1]: ingresso nella directory «/home/jonny/Scrivania/git-2.29.2/Documentation»
make[2]: ingresso nella directory «/home/jonny/Scrivania/git-2.29.2»
make[2]: «GIT-VERSION-FILE» è aggiornato.
make[2]: uscita dalla directory «/home/jonny/Scrivania/git-2.29.2»
    ASCIIDOC git-rm.html
/bin/sh: 2: asciidoc: not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:344: git-rm.html] Errore 127
make[1]: uscita dalla directory «/home/jonny/Scrivania/git-2.29.2/Documentation»
make: *** [Makefile:2551: doc] Errore 2
```

How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Install asciidoc?

Comment: Is there some reason why you're building from source instead of using a package manager?

Comment: The easiest way forward for you is to run this: `sudo apt install git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building Git from source is not entirely trivial: you must install a lot of dependencies, and simply cloning the Git source tree (from any of the various mirrors) doesn't give you the list of dependencies (which are themselves OS-dependent).

As [matt noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616851/why-do-i-get-this-strange-error-in-installing-git-in-ubuntu-20#comment114253857_64616851), you will need to install asciidoc.  You must also install compilers and other tools.  You may have installed most of them already, but expect to stumble across various missing ones as you go.  Just install them and try again until you have the list of everything you need (or find a list from someone who has made a list for your particular OS).

Comment: I obtain other errors from conflicting python versions. If it is the case, I will open an other issue.